# Why does iptables restart cause connectivity timeout for about a minute?

Tags: linux, iptables, reboot, timeout

I have a centos 6.5 64bit router with 3 nics.
The box is configured to route 2 networks.
netA - eth1 [ about 10 clients ] 
netB - eth2 [ about 100 clients ] 
provider - eth0 [ fiber to isp ]

I have a custom script that initializes the firewall and also sets marks in mangle table for qos purposes.
The script initializes by flushing all rules in all tables.
The -F -X drill for filter nat mangle and then it begins to compose the rules.
I also have the nf_conntrack module loaded and my script does not unload it.
Note that I don't use the official rhel firewall scripts.

Everything works until I run the script for various reasons (modify certain qos requirements, filter certain users, ports etc whathaveyou).
At that time my ssh connection to the box freezes and i can't even ping it.
Of course there's no internet connectivity and my lan is frozen. 
Funny thing the netA computers are only cut off for a few seconds but the netB lan looses connectivity for about a minute or two. 
Then everything is back to normal.

Where do I start ?

Comment: I'd look at the sequence that the rules are loaded. If `Net A`'s rules are all at the top, and there are a lot of them, and `Net B`'s rules are all at the bottom, then the time needed to run through all of `Net A`'s rules could be up to a  minute before `Net B`'s rules are run.

Comment: What @Lawrence says is especially true if you change default policies at the top, and the def.pol are REJECT. In this case, under his assumptions, it will take A little time to regain connectivity, and a long time for B to do the same. Of course this is the right thing to do: if you add def.policies at then end, for some time someone will be able to circumvent iptables, and then the ESTABLISHED, RELATED rule will save these (dangerous) connections.

Comment: The number of rules has a significant impact on performance when loading rules.  Once your iptables is the way you want it **iptables-save** and **iptables-restore** should be all you ever need to save/reload iptables config. Modules and **ipset** sets, and etc could be scripted separately.  We have no idea how fast the CPU or how much RAM it has so it could be hardware limitations.

Comment: iptables wise, It has default accept policy with a bottom DROP rule.
Hardware wise it has a Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 2.66GHz cpu with 2 cores and 1 gb ram.

Comment: How many rules do you have?  #1 0-50  #2 50-100 #3 100-200 #4  200-400 #5 400-500 #6 500+ insanity.

Comment: oh well.
143 filter
208 nat
316 mangle 
Kind of makes it "crazy" :))